# Eclipse Indigo with Subclipse and draw2d

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, draw2d

I've just installed Eclipse Indigo and Subclipse 1.6.17 on RHEL 5.4.

I had to deselect the  without the Subversion Revision Graph because it requires the draw2d plugin.

I am working on a standalone system, so I have downloaded and transfered the GEF-draw2d-3.7.0M5.zip but when I select it in the software install tool, I get the response "Could not find jar:file//GEF-draw2d-3.7.0M5.zip!/

The path is the same as for subclipse (jar:file//site-1.6.17.zip!/)

Has anyone else had this problem?

thanks

dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have the wrong file, you should download the [All-In-One Update Site](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/download.php?file=/tools/gef/downloads/drops/3.7.0/S201102011016/GEF-Update-3.7.0M5.zip) not the runtime/SDK.